# Python multiple regex matching in a single statement

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a large Python string as shown below.

```
large_string = "The MIT License (MIT)\n\nCopyright (c) [year] [fullname]\n\nPermission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a ...."
```

I want to replace "[year]" in the string with current year and "[fullname]" with a user provided name. I am using the re library in python to do this task.

```
import re
import datetime

def pattern_replace(large_string, name):
    year = datetime.now().year
    large_string = re.sub('\[year\]', str(year), large_string)
    large_string = re.sub('\[fullname\]', name, large_string)
    return large_string
```

But I think it's not the appropriate way. I have never really used regex matching before but I think there should be a more Pythonic way to combine the two re.sub statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is much simpler if you simply do it with two regular expressions, rather than one.

If you combine them into one, you make it more fragile (i.e. dependent on the ordering of the two things), and the regular expression needs to be more complex.

You could do something like:

```
large_string = re.sub('\[year\](.*?)\[fullname\]', str(year) + '\g<1>' + name, large_string)
```

Ask yourself which you find easier to read, though. I would recommend going with that option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It makes sense to use the first approach as code readability is really important.

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that the string is rewritten to use `{year}` and `{fullname}`, you can then use the [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to fill them in:

```
from datetime import datetime

def pattern_replace(large_string, name):
    return large_string.format(
        year=datetime.now().year,
        name=name,
    )
```